# Laravel Livewire failed to upload file on vps server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, vps, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel webapp running on Centos 7 vps, it have a form with file upload using Livewire.

[image]

Everytime after I select the file, it always return an error 500 (Internal Server Error).[image]

and here is the error on UploadManager.js
[image]

all folder in server I set to 0777, it should be writable.
i'm using cpanel in vps to upload laravel project.

here is in my blade.php file

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
...
<div class="form-group required">
            <label for="fl_ktp" class="control-label">Upload KTP: (max. 3 MB)</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control {{$errors->first('fl_ktp') ? "is-invalid" : "" }}" wire:model="fl_ktp">
            @error('fl_ktp') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div> @enderror
        </div>
...
</form>
```

can you guys help me, is there something I missed to configure? because it's running well on my local.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message meaning something went wrong. Check your php error log for the exact issue.

Comment: Can you check your Logs inside Laravel ? Storage/logs ? Can you try it with small few KBs file size ?

Comment: Here is what I found in Storage/logs/laravel.log:

[2022-03-01 00:47:37] local.ERROR: Class "finfo" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"finfo\" not found at /home/adminbtnrumah/public_html/btn-microsite/vendor/league/mime-type-detection/src/FinfoMimeTypeDetector.php:36)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/adminbtnrumah/public_html/btn-microsite/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Local/LocalFilesystemAdapter.php(95): League\\MimeTypeDetection\\FinfoMimeTypeDetector->__construct()

it means I have to update something? 
thanks in advance @gguney

Comment: I tested it using 5kb file btw

Answer (score 0):

I  fixed it by installing the "fileinfo" extension on my VPS server and enabling "allow_url_fopen".

You can rely on the following link to install an extension and, instead of installing "mbstring", use it to install "fileinfo":

https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/enable-mbstring-extension-whm-cpanel-vps-servers.html

Then, for enabling "allow_url_fopen":

[image: screenshot]